# Facepile does not work on mobile

Tags: facebook, facepile

I'm trying to get the Facebook Facepile on a webpage. It shows fine on the desktop using the code from Fecebook's website (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/), but just doesn't show up on any mobile device. I've tried on an iPhone, iPad and Galaxy Nexus.

Is it supposed to not work on mobile devices at all, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you found anything yet for this?? if yes, can you please update me on this. i also have to incorporate facepile in my mobile app. thanks.